# Best way to handle increasing number of objects

Tags: three.js

I've recently started experimenting with webgl.

I've seen a lot of demos, that create tens of thousands of objects and they work fluently (60fps).

I'm needing to create a scene where I start with no objects, and the number goes up to a few thousands of objects over time. How can a situation like this be handled?

I've thought of creating the objects as a single gigantic on start and just modifying their vertices to position them into the field of view of the camera when they need to "born"; but this workaround seemed like too much work to do.

Here is an example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fmsqB?editors=001

Tried to make the code as clear as possible, but check out this part

```
function populate(){
  if (count < maxcount){
    sph = sphere.clone();
    scene.add(sph);
    sphere.position.x = Rand(-10,10);
    sphere.position.y = Rand(-10,10);
    sphere.position.z = Rand(-10,10);
    count +=1;
    console.log(count);
  };
};
```

You can see that even with a few thousand lowest subdivision spheres, the FPS goes down pretty quickly (for the machine I'm using right now it goes down to around 20 fps with 5-6k spheres)

Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are creating single Three.Meshes.
What you are looking for is a way to recude draw calls and/or use a better internal structure, namely Buffergeometry. See the examples that come with Three.js

You can also try merging the spheres after you create them. See here

http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/10/05/performance-merging-geometry/

Comment: I can't seem to find any proper example of buffergeometry that clearly explains what's going on. Most of the buffergeometry examples just spam random triangles around. What if we want to duplicate a cube, or a sphere?

Comment: Also, the same applies to merging the geometry. If I merge the geometry with the "rest of the things created" for every single item I create in a for loop, it takes half minute before everything's populated. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: well I do not know your use-case. Concerning the BufferGeometry: It is just some arrays that hold the information. Dig deeper there to really get nice performance but it is a steep learning curve. The example shows how to set up the arrays to draw from them. You will have to read up on the code and also on WebGL Buffers to understand

http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=370

as for merging: Maybe merge not for every geometry creation, maybe every 50 Meshes? You will need to find a sweet spot there and this is also depending on your use case and what you want to do.

Comment: how can I merge 50 meshes together, that's the problem. I know how to merge one single mesh via .merge, but how about 50?